# Prevent comments containing html links from beeing validated

Tags: 7, comments, advertising

Seems very simple and I thought a module for that would be easy to find but no..
I've got a website that's beeing infested by spambots in node comments.

You're probably going to tell to disable full HTML input format, but this doesn't block comments, it just stops the links from linking; but the pollution is still there..

My normal users usually don't post any links. When I say links I mean html links:

```
<a href="http://bloodyspamwebsite.com">Blah</a>
```

So all I want to do is block all comments containing one or more of these html links.

I found [blockanonymouslinks](http://drupal.org/project/blockanonymouslinks) but this seems to only work for anonymous users. My spammers are logged-in users.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you go for [Mollom](http://drupal.org/project/mollom)

> Mollom may block a post outright if it is from a known spammer. If
>   Mollom is unsure how to classify a post, it may require the completion
>   of a CAPTCHA to accept the post. Posts that do not match a "spammy"
>   text pattern and do not originate from known spammers are accepted
>   without the need to complete a CAPTCHA. Essentially, Mollom acts as a
>   proactive content moderator that is on the job 24 hours a day, 7 days
>   a week.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry, forgot to mention it, but Mollom is a paid solution, I need a free solution.